# Convert AM/PM to 24-Hour Time In Big Query Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

How would I convert the following AM/PM value to the 24-hour clock time in Big Query standard SQL?

created_date
8/30/2018 2:23:38 PM

created_date
2018-08-30 14:23:38 UTC

Answer (score 5):

First parse the timestamp string as a `TIMESTAMP` value, then format it in the desired way:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP(
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z',
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', created_date)
  ) AS created_date
FROM (
  SELECT '8/30/2018 2:23:38 PM' AS created_date
);
+-------------------------+
| created_date            |
+-------------------------+
| 2018-08-30 14:23:38 UTC |
+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this option

RPAD(FORMAT_DATETIME('%F %k:%M:%S', '2023-06-23 23:59:59'), 19, ' ')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).